# Set default formatting for a timestamp, by session or globally

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

In Postgres, is it possible to change the default format mask for a timestamp?
Right now comes back as:

```
2012-01-03 20:27:53.611489
```

I would like resolution to minute like this:

```
2012-01-03 20:27
```

I know I can do this on individual columns with `to_char() as` or stripped down with a `substr()` by the receiving app, but having it formatted correctly initially would save a lot of work and reduce a lot of errors.

Comment: which client application are you using?

Comment: prototype in php, moving to node.js in about 6 mo

Comment: Then this would be a php setting to change, not a Postgres setting.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you could be right.  was hoping some `locale` like setting might be available.  `locale` formats, but formats are fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In postgres, you **can** change the default format mask for datetimes - using the `set datestyle` option; the available options can be found [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/datatype-datetime.html) (see 8.5.2. Date/Time Output).

Unfortunately, all the available options include the number of seconds - you will therefore need to reformat them either in the query or the application code (if applicable).

Answer (score 15):

In PostgreSQL, The formatting of timestamps is independent of storage.  One answer is to use `to_char` and format the timestamp to whatever format you need at the moment you need it, like this:

```
select to_char(current_timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:MI:SS.MS');

select to_timestamp('2012-10-11 12:13:14.123', 
     'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:MI:SS.MS')::timestamp;
```

But if you must set the default formatting:

**Change the postgresql timestamp format globally:**

Take a look at your timezone, run this as an sql query:

```
show timezone
Result: "US/Eastern"
```

So when you are printing out current_timestamp, you see this:

```
select current_timestamp
Result: 2012-10-23 20:58:35.422282-04
```

The `-04` at the end is your time zone relative to UTC.  You can change your timezone with:

```
set timezone = 'US/Pacific'
```

Then:

```
select current_timestamp
Result: 2012-10-23 18:00:38.773296-07
```

So notice the `-07` there, that means we Pacific is 7 hours away from UTC.  How do I make that unsightly timezone go away?  One way is just to make a table, it defaults to a timestamp without timezone:

```
CREATE TABLE worse_than_fail_table
(
    mykey          INT unique not null,
    fail_date      TIMESTAMP not null
);
```

Then if you add a timestamp to that table and select from it

```
select fail_date from worse_than_fail_table
Result: 2012-10-23 21:09:39.335146
```

yay, no timezone on the end.  But you want more control over how the timestamp shows up by default!  You could do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE moo (
    key     int PRIMARY KEY,
    boo     text NOT NULL DEFAULT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'YYYYMM')
);
```

It's a text field which gives you more control over how it shows up by default when you do a `select somecolumns from sometable`.  Notice you can cast a string to timestamp:

```
select '2012-10-11 12:13:14.56789'::timestamp
Result: 2012-10-11 12:13:14.56789
```

You could cast a current_timestamp to `timestamp` which removes the timezone:

```
select current_timestamp::timestamp
Result: 2012-10-23 21:18:05.107047
```

You can get rid of the timezone like this:

```
select current_timestamp at time zone 'UTC'
Result: "2012-10-24 01:40:10.543251"
```

But if you really want the timezone back you can do this:

```
select current_timestamp::timestamp with time zone
Result: 2012-10-23 21:20:21.256478-04
```

You can yank out what you want with extract:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');
Result: 20
```

And this monstrosity:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40-05' AT TIME ZONE 'EST';
Result: 2001-02-16 20:38:40
```

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Answer (score 7):

`to_char()` is used to create a string literal. If you want a different **timestamp value**, use [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC):

```
date_trunc('minute', now())
```

For converting literal **input**, use [`to_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE):

```
to_timestamp('2012-01-03 20:27:53.611489', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
```

This returns `timestamptz`. Cast to `timestamp [without time zone]` by appending `::timestamp` (which assumes your current `timezone` setting), or with the `AT TIME ZONE` construct to define a time zone explicitly.

To my knowledge, there is no setting in PostgreSQL that would trim seconds from timestamp literals by default.

Comment: thanks, but the issue is not the value of the timestamp but rather its string representation when selected.  in this app, a timestamp presented to the user is always rounded to the nearest minute - having to do with display, not with data.  was looking for a way to do this without a `to_char()` on each column of each select.

Comment: @ccyoung: If you want to **round** to the nearest minute, `to_char()` connot help you either. You can only truncate with it. Anyway, this sounds like a job for the **client**, not for the database. a_horse_with_no_name is on the right track.

Comment: theoretically I'm sure you're probably right, but as a matter of practice have almost always put date formatting and arithmetic in SQL since it's so much better at it than javascript or php.

Comment: btw, insightful about **round** vs **truncate** with `to_char()` - fortunately this is the behavior expected